# Calibre is changing HTML content while converting

Tags: calibre, html, css

I used Calibre to convert my HTML file to EPUB3 and check it with its viewer
and I notice that a lot of syles are missing !!!!

so I check the created ebook's files using calibre local editor
and what I came up with is all div's class has changed (it add calibre1 to each div or change content-block to content-block1 for example )

so is there any option to ignore those changes?

mean force calibre to import the file without adding any additional class or divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally to maximize [compatibility and robustness](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#id33), epub converters will strip as much styling out as possible to still maintain formatting, so I would encourage you to just deal with it.

If you absolutely have to keep original styling you can edit the archive using a program like [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). Open the archive and find the .css file within. There is probably significant changes made to classes and ids so it may take quite a bit of fiddling.